# Use ansible to insert into etc hosts file

Tags: ansible

I want to insert the following entry into the */etc/hosts* file somehow using Ansible.

```
10.33.5.44 ip-10-33-5-44
```

Here, the schema is that the ip should have an alias corresponding to the IP, prefixed with `ip-` and where the dot `.` would be replaced by dash `-`.

But to get this IP, I can only think of doing the host command on a DNS name e.g.

```
host euwest2-test-box.company.com
> euwest2-test-box.company.com has address 10.33.5.44
```

Can anyone suggest how to get that to work? Is it possible?

Comment: So you just want in your host to make an alias prefixing the ip with `ip-` ?

Comment: yes, prefixed with ip- and also replace dots with "-"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`dig`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html) lookup in order to achieve this. Then add the lines in the hosts file with [`lineinefile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html).

**Please mind** that the module `dig` needs the Python library `dnspython` to operate. So you might want to install it as well with Ansible.

So, given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - package:
        name: py-dnspython
        state: present
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts
        line: "{{ item }} ip-{{ item | replace('.', '-') }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dig', 'stackoverflow.com.').split(',') }}"
```

This gives the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [package] *****************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=151.101.1.69)
changed: [localhost] => (item=151.101.65.69)
changed: [localhost] => (item=151.101.129.69)
changed: [localhost] => (item=151.101.193.69)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And populate the hosts file accordingly:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  21eef8264e0c
151.101.1.69 ip-151-101-1-69
151.101.65.69 ip-151-101-65-69
151.101.129.69 ip-151-101-129-69
151.101.193.69 ip-151-101-193-69
```

Comment: Great stuff, I do however get a permission denied error. I tried using `become: true` but that didn't work either. Any ideas? - See: https://justpaste.it/6qxot

Comment: You need to become the root user indeed on this very first package task, if you are not already

Comment: Maybe you have an upper level `become_user` set to another user? If so, you'll need to add both `become: true` and `become_user: root` in the `package` task.

Comment: Right, added that. Also... is there any way to append a command to it. I wanted to run it inside a conda environment because I have conda running. When I install `dnspython` and then run your solution... it complains that there is no package called dnspython.

Comment: I tried but didn't work: `loop: "source /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/activate myCondaEnv {{ lookup('dig', 'stackoverflow.com.').split(',') }}"`

Comment: ... you cannot just put random commands like that wherever you are pleased in Ansible. Either way you are deviating from your original question. If you have a follow up, please open a new question.